# Simplify $A!B + A!C + BC$

Tags: logic

Could someone help me simplify this logical expression: $A!B + A!C + BC$ ?

I know the identities:

$A + AB = A$

$A + !AB = A + B$

$(A + B)(A + C) = A + BC$

but I'm not sure what the first step in simplification would be.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third identity to have:

$$(A!B+A!C)+BC\equiv(A!B+A!C+B)(A!B+A!C+C)$$

Then use the second identity to have (and commutativity):
$$(A!B+A!C+B)(A!B+A!C+C)\equiv(B+A+A!C)(C+A+A!B)$$

Finally (almost), use the first identity to have:
$$(A+B+A!C)(A+C+A!B)\equiv(A+B)(A+C)$$

...and I'll let you finish on your own from here.

Answer (score 0):

*There is no such thing as simplest form*.  You can literally apply any of the transforms to your problem and claim to be done.

One form that could be considered the answer is what Asaf Karagila suggests, $(A + B)(A + C)$.  That is called product of sums.  He showed how to derive that.

Another possible answer is $A + BC$.  This is called sum of products. Another possible answer is $A!BC + AB!C + ABC + A!B!C + A!BC$.  That is just an enumeration of satisfying values.

Another possible answer is $A \text{ xor } !B \text{ xor } BC$.  Your relations don't support xor, but it is a possible "simplified answer".

To apply the identities, I suggest you look at what each relation does.  The first removes an entire variable.  The second removes a negation.  The third reduces the number of operations.  Then decide on what you need for your application and apply as necessary.

Comment: Actually, I was driving towards $A+BC$. But this is clearly an application of the third identity again, which is what I meant by the last line "I'll let you finish on your own from here".

Comment: Also, simplest can be taken as a shorthand for "shortest" or "involving least possible alternating operations" or a combination of these sort of minimality requirements. Of course there might not be "the simplest", but in those cases "a simplest" certainly exists.